# Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file with type 'application/javascript'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed oclazyload with bower
in my .js file I require the module

```
`//= require oclazyLoad`
```

works fine when I am trying to deploy I am getting an error

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'oclazyLoad' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths:
........
mypath/releases/20170622133435/vendor/assets/bower_components
```

So I ssh to the server and look at this path

```
mypath/releases/20170622133435/vendor/assets/bower_components
```

The folder of oclazyload bower module is there but I am still getting this error.
I am stuck don't know how to debug this.

Comment: Did you found `oclazyLoad.js` file in  `mypath/releases/20170622133435/vendor/assets/bower_components` folder?

Comment: I have found the a folder named oclazyload with the bower.json file with an entry: 
"main": "dist/ocLazyLoad.js",

Comment: You can try change the require path as `//= require oclazyLoad/dist/oclazyLoad` or use a absoulute path `//= require mypath/releases/20170622133435/vendor/assets/bower_component‌​s/oclazyLoad/dist/oclazyLoad`